# How to set up settings.py on Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, settings, webapp2

I changed from GAE/Py2.5 to 2.7 and from Django0.9 to Django1.2.
I am useing relative paths extends tag to Template Engine When caused TemplateDoesNotExist error and disable.

It's use Template “google.appengine.ext.webapp.template”.
I think , how do I set up your own loader to TEMPLATE_LOADERS or setting the template path TEMPLATE_DIRS.

However, I don't know how to set.
Please tell me how to set up.

Comment: Check your python sys.path (print and show it)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use just a regular requesthandler? What happens if you test:

```
class Home(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    data = {}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/main.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, data))
```

Comment: he maybe using django like request handler.